# Talkback is not getting enabled through adb shell

Tags: automation, settings, accessibilityservice, talkback, accessibility

I've tried the command `adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.android.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService` to enable talkback from adb shell. It's toggling the ui button which signifies the status of talkback, but talkback is not actually getting enabled.
I am trying to enable talkback programmatically for android 6.0. Is there any other way thorough which I can enable it?

Answer (score 27):

Commands to toggle TalkBack:

```
// disable
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.android.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService

// enable
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService
```

Kudos to @zeh

Comment: Any clue how to change speed of talkback with adb too?

Answer (score 3):

For convenience, I use a shell script to toggle this setting.

```
output=$(adb shell settings get secure enabled_accessibility_services)

if [[ "$output" == "com.android.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService" ]]; then
  adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService
else
  adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.android.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this alongside any other accessibility services or UI Automation (which utilizes the accessibility APIs)?  Accessibility services are only allowed to run one at a time, and attempting otherwise will cause exceptions all over the place.  Check LogCat and see if TalkBack is attempting to start up, but throwing exceptions when doing so.